# How to deploy chatbot (NodeJS) In Azure without Bitbucket connection

Tags: node.js, azure, bitbucket, chatbot, azure-deployment

I want to display a chatbot on Microsoft Azure. I've looked at the different alternatives and I can't find a way to do what I want. It's the first time I've ever used Azure and it's probably simple.

The code for this bot is in an organization's Bitbucket repository. I mean, I can't use the continuous deployment that Azure offers because I can't access the organization's Bitbucket. Is there an API I can call or a method for displaying my code without Azure needing to connect to my repository? Well, publishing the bot in a Bitbucket on the Internet (outside the organization) is restricted.

The bot is in NodeJS and I have seen the npm run azure-publish command which may be the way.

Thank you very much for your time.

---

PS1: Ideally, we should push, not Azure pull.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved my problem by using the command:

```
npm run azure-publish
```

Which internally makes a node of a **publish.js** file in which I specify the necessary parameters for the connection, the path to the ZIP, etc.

What I can't do is a callback to let me know if the deployment was successful, but that's already a straightforward question and I'm with it.

I hope I can be of help to other people. Any additional questions, do not hesitate to ask.